# How to set properties of a root view controller before being presented?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, presentviewcontroller, rootview

I have a certain `UINavigationController` in `storyboard` I present modally from another view controller:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myNavController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavController"];
[self presentViewController:myNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This navigation controller has set another `UIViewController` as its root view controller in `storyboard`. I'd like to set some properties for this root view controller before it is shown, but I tried this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myNavController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavController"];
[self presentViewController:myNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
 MyRootViewController *myRootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myRootViewController"];
[myRootViewController setSelectedItem:selectedItem];
[myRootViewController setDelegate:self];
```

But the root view controller doesn't seem to be loaded yet when I try to set its properties...

How could I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had debugged, you will find the `myRootViewController` made by `MyRootViewController *myRootViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myRootViewController"];`
 isn't the `myNavController`'s real rootViewController.

This method `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` just give you a whole new UIViewController instance.

So, If you want get the real rootViewController, just replace it with following:

```c
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *myNavController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myNavController"];

 MyRootViewController *myRootViewController = myNavController.viewControllers[0];
[myRootViewController setSelectedItem:selectedItem];
[myRootViewController setDelegate:self];

[self presentViewController:myNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```